# Switch to LyX Code Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: lyx

In LyX, is there a keyboard shortcut to switch from the standard input to LyX code input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, then choose C from the menu.